# Unity ERROR when I try to open any project on 2021 LTS version

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Hello so I work in unity at an AR project and few days ago I buy a MacBook Pro because I want to deploy the app on iPhone and I need Xcode. The problem is that I install 2021.3.1f1 editor because is the version requested for unity tutorial in AR and when I try to open any project even when I create a new one, when the project open it says me to open in safe mode and if I ignore it, throws me this error: Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 137." The only way to make it work it was to instal 2020 editor, but maybe you know other method cause I really need to use the 2021 version. I tried to delete library folder from project and temp and a lot of 2021 versions but nothing worked.